# How to change ng-include inside firebase firestore function

Tags: html, angularjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

When I click on continue button it checks clients ID in firestore database and if ID does'nt exist then `$scope.filePath = "createClient.htm"` is called. everything is working fine but when I call this piece of code inside firebase function nothing happens

**Inside HTML**

```
<div ng-include="filePath" class="ng-scope">
    <div  class="offset-1 offset-sm-2 col-11 col-sm-7">
        <h2>Enter Client ID</h2>
        <br>

        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="exampleInputEmail1">ID</label>
          <input id="client_id" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Client ID">
        </div>


        <div class="float-right">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Cancel</button>
        <button type="button" ng-click="searchClient()" class="btn btn-success">Continue</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Internal Script**

```
<script> 


        $scope.searchClient = function()

    {
        //$scope.filePath = "createClient.htm"; it works here

        var id= document.getElementById('client_id').value;
            db.collection("clients")      // db is firestore reference
                .where("c_id","==",id)
                .get()
                .then(function(querySnapshot) 
                {

                    querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) 
                        {
                            if(!doc.exists)
                                {
                                    console.log("Client Does'nt Exist");
    $scope.filePath = "createClient.htm";  // but doesnt  works here inside this firebase function
                                }
                        }
                        );

                }
                );
            }
        };
</script>
```

when console.log is shown and firebase function are fully executed then if I click on "Continue" Button again it works fine and content of createClient.htm is shown inside ng-include="filePath". why i need to click twice ?

Comment: Need to call $scope.$apply since you are updating scope outside angular context

Comment: @charlietfl thankyou so much it works for me.